# Quadratic equation and inequality, why is this method wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have this inequality

> $$
> (x-3)^2<5 \tag1
> $$

**But why is the following method wrong?**

Add $-5$ to both sides and expand the square
\begin{align}
x^2-6x+9-5&<0 \\
x^2-6x+4&<0 
\end{align}
And completing the square of $x^2-6x+4<0$ gives:
\begin{align}
x^2-6x+ (6/2)^2-(6/2)^2+4&<0 \\
(x-3)^2-3^2+4&<0 \\
(x-3)^2&<5  \\
\end{align}
Squaring and adding $3$ to both sides:
\begin{align}
x<3\pm\sqrt 5 \tag 2
\end{align}
So I have:
\begin{align}
x&<3+\sqrt 5 \tag 3\\
x&<3-\sqrt 5 \tag 4
\end{align}
Why is this method wrong?

**From the book:** For $(x-3)^2<5$ we have two solutions
\begin{align}
x-3&<\sqrt 5 \tag 5\\
-(x-3)&<\sqrt 5 \tag 6
\end{align}
So 
\begin{align}
x&<3+\sqrt 5 \tag 7\\
x&>3-\sqrt 5 \tag 8
\end{align}

$(7)$ is the same as my $(3)$, but $(4)$ is not $(8)$. What is wrong with my method?

Comment: if $x^2 \lt y^2 \implies  \boxed { -y \lt x \lt y}$

Comment: "squaring" is not a good method.  From the correct $-2<-1$, squaring would yield the incorrect $4 < 1$.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Is it really "implies" and not equivalent $\iff$?

Answer (score 1):

Your first few sequence of operations is completely unnecessary. Note that you eventually end up with the original inequality.

Well, so what's wrong? The problem is when you go from $(x-3)^2<5$ to $x<3\pm\sqrt 5$ by "squaring" and adding three to both sides. First, I think you meant to *extract square roots,* not to square. But if you do that you get this $\sqrt{(x-3)^2}<\sqrt 5,$ or in other words $$|x-3|<\sqrt 5.$$ This may be written as $$\pm(x-3)<\sqrt 5.$$ These are actually two inequalities, $x-3<\sqrt 5,$ or $-(x-3)<\sqrt 5.$ So your error is apparent in that you changed the last inequality to $x-3<-\sqrt 5.$ But that's wrong, for you should instead have $$x-3\color{red}{>}-\sqrt 5.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method  is wrong when you translate $(x-3)^2<5$ into $x<3\pm\sqrt 5$, which means  nothing.

Actually the very short way to solve the inequation uses the basic fact that, for *nonnegative* numbers, $\;A^2<B\iff A<\sqrt B$, $\;$so
$$(x-3)^2<5\iff|x-3|<\sqrt 5\iff 3-\sqrt 5<x<3+\sqrt 5.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well you see there is a huge difference between inequality and equality. In inequality a small change can alter sign of the inequality like multiplying by -1. Likewise here take $y^2<5$

Now if you solve like a quadratic equality it becomes $y<\sqrt{5}$ and $y<- \sqrt{5}$
Let's assume this is the solution let's take $y=-\sqrt{10}$ .This is true if we take second inequality we assumed to be true. Substitute y into it's original inequality. You'll get $10<5$ which is obviously not true . It is true if $y>- \sqrt{5}$

So for $y^2<a$ where $a>0$ inequality becomes $- \sqrt{a}<y<\sqrt{a}$

Answer (score 0):

From $(x-3)^2 \lt 5$ you could take the square root of both sides of the equation, giving

$$\left| x-3 \right| \lt \sqrt{5}$$
which is equivalent to
$$-\sqrt{5}\lt x-3 \lt \sqrt{5}$$
$$3-\sqrt{5}\lt x \lt 3+\sqrt{5}$$

Another way of understanding what you did wrong it to ask yourself how $x$ can be less than $3-\sqrt{5}$ if $3-\sqrt{5}$ is $x$'s lower bound?